# Apple Computers barely visible screen pixel grid noise

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini

Few years ago I noticed that some of my friends Apple devices such as Macbooks, iMacs, Macminis have barely visible pixel grid over image. Mostly visible on gray-ish colors looks like **very fine noise** over image. But I never had it on my devices.

This year i got new **2020 M1 MacMini** with same issue. **Device runs absolutely fine**, but while photo editing that grid annoys me big time because it's affect real-end result.

I tried **different monitors** and even **TV** same thing. **Device connected over UPS** so grid noise excluded. Out of curiosity **disabled Wi-Fi and BT**, no change.

Is anyone else had this issue before? May be some of the settings affect it?

Running Big-Sur 11.1

**Here is picture with issue presented:**

[image]

**UPDATE: Today i got HDMI 2.0 Screen and image looks perfect, picture below:**

[image]

Comment: Could you get a photo of it - I presume it wouldn't show on a screenshot.

Comment: It's hard to get picture, looks like noise is dynamic, for eye it's looks static tho. I tried my best to make one, updated topic. Also i got HDMI 2.0 monitor today and it has no issues over 2.0